# Printing next working day in bash given list of holidays

Tags: bash, scripts, date

I want to generate a simple file **dates.txt** containing the following two dates:

Todays_trading_Date Next_Trading_Date

Trading days are only weekdays which do not fall on a given list of holidays below:

```
cat holiday_list.txt
20190304
20190321
20190417
20190419
20190429
20190501
20190605
20190812
20190815
20190902
20190910
20191002
20191008
20191028
20191112
20191225
```

for eg: If we run the script today on 14th of Aug, 2019- (Please note that 15th of Aug 2019 is in the holiday_list.txt as 20190815) the output will be as follows:

```
14-Aug-2019 16-Aug-2019
```

I have searched and found a similar problem at this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516735/get-next-working-day-using-variable) to get the next weekday.

```
last_day=20190426
 date -d "$last_day +$( if [ `date -d $last_day +%w` == 5 ]; then echo 3; elif [ `date -d $last_day +%w` == 6 ]; then echo 2; else echo 1; fi ) days" +"%Y%m%d"
```

I have used the above code to generate dates.txt in the script below to create dates.txt

```
#!/bin/bash

last_day=`date +%Y%m%d`

last_day=`date +%d-%b-%Y`
printf $last_day > dates.txt
printf " " >> dates.txt
date -d "$last_day +$( if [ `date -d $last_day +%w` == 5 ]; then echo 3; elif [ `date -d $last_day +%w` == 6 ]; then echo 2; else echo 1; fi ) days" +"%d-%b-%Y" >> dates.txt
```

The script prints out today's date and the next working day (i.e. weekday) in a file. 
However, when I try to run an if condition to detect if a date is in the holiday_list.txt file, the script always goes into the else part even if the next_day string is present in holiday_list.txt

```
if grep -Fxq "$next_day" holiday_list.txt
then
    Do this

else 
    Do other thing
fi
```

Please let me know if something I am missing here

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [ask]. I'm looking for some research effort on your part. Please [edit] and add your attempt at implementing this. As well, add the contents of holiday_list.txt. Read [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on Stack Overflow for more pointers.

Comment: As well, the last line of your script is awfully long. It would help if you broke it up. BTW, [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is a great resource for debugging shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

In general, one does something like:

```
date_is_ok=0
while [[ $date_is_ok = 0 ]] ; do
    new_date=generate_the_date
    grep -q "$new_date" holiday_list.txt
    date_is_ok=$?
done
```

Taking advantage of `grep`'s

```
−q        Quiet.  Nothing  shall be written to the standard output, regardless of matching
          lines. Exit with zero status if an input line is selected.
```